# Como funciona o deslocamento de bits em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, bit

Gostaria de entender como funciona o deslocamento de bits em **C/C++**. Também gostaria de entender como o processador realiza os cálculos e como ele trata tudo isto.

Tenho alguns exemplos em **C/C++**:

```
void USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr0){
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr0>>8); //Ajusta a taxa de transmissão
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr0;

    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);     //Habilita a transmissão e a recepção
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00);   //modo assíncrono, 8 bits de dados, 1 bit de parada, sem paridade
}
```

Também gostaria de entender qual a diferença entre **<<** e **>>**.

**Edit**

```
int x = 1; 
x = (x << 8);
```

`x` vai ser `0001 0000 0000` ?

O que ocorre se eu "ultrapasso" o número de bits de uma variável? Exemplo:

```
int x = 1; 
//Representação na memória: 
//{4º byte} {3º byte} {2º byte} {1º byte} 
//0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 
x = (x << 50); //Como ficaria?
```

**Edit 2:**

Que operações o processador faz para que o valor:

```
int x = 1;          //Corresponde a 0000 0001
```

Fique desta forma na memória:

```
int x1 = (x << 1);  //Corresponde a 0000 0010
```

Como ele calcula isto? Ele armazena em uma "variável" (registrador) temporária e depois devolve a posição original? Faz algum cálculo matemático? (qual?) ou é só manipulação de memória?

Comment: O tom das suas perguntas normalmente me faz lembrar [deste cara...](http://abstrusegoose.com/98)

Comment: Hahaha, ri muito lendo essa tirinha. Me identifiquei bastante. Gosto de tentar compreender tudo a nível de hardware.

Comment: [Real programmers use butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Os operadores de deslocamento de bits "movem" todos os bits da variável para esquerda ou direita.

C\C++ possui os operadores:

> **>>** Deslocamento para Direita
>
> **<<** Deslocamento para Esquerda

Por exemplo, se deslocar uma variável `x` a esquerda:

```
int x = 1; // 0000 0001

int x0 = (x << 0); // 0000 0001 Não deslocado
int x1 = (x << 1); // 0000 0010
int x2 = (x << 2); // 0000 0100
int x3 = (x << 3); // 0000 1000
int x4 = (x << 4); // 0001 0000
int x5 = (x << 5); // 0010 0000
int x6 = (x << 6); // 0100 0000
int x7 = (x << 7); // 1000 0000
```

Agora se deslocar a direita:

```
int x = 128; // 1000 0000

int x0 = (x >> 0); // 1000 0000 Não deslocado
int x1 = (x >> 1); // 0100 0000
int x2 = (x >> 2); // 0010 0000
int x3 = (x >> 3); // 0001 0000
int x4 = (x >> 4); // 0000 1000
int x5 = (x >> 5); // 0000 0100
int x6 = (x >> 6); // 0000 0010
int x7 = (x >> 7); // 0000 0001
```

---

No seu exemplo eles são utilizados possivelmente, para configurar uma comunicação serial (ou algo do tipo), na qual os deslocamentos são usados para ativar de forma mais simples os bits de configuração.

Por exemplo, se eu quero ativar alguns bits específicos de uma variável `UCSR0B`, assumindo que `RXEN0` é 4 e `TXEN0` é 3:

```
(1<<RXEN0) -> (1 << 4) -> (00000001 << 4) -> (00010000)
(1<<TXEN0) -> (1 << 3) -> (00000001 << 3) -> (00001000)
```

O que é o mesmo que fazer:

```
UCSR0B = 0x10 | 0x8;
```

Essa operação `(1 << VALOR)` é uma forma de dizer ao compilador "eu quero número cujo bit número *VALOR* (para base zero) seja 1 e o resto 0".

---

Para o caso de se ultrapassar os limites de uma variável, o resultado é indefinido, conforme diz no padrão:

> (C11, 6.5.7p3) "If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the
>   behavior is undefined"
>
> (C++11, 5.8p1) "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is
>   negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the
>   promoted left operand."

Se você precisa de um limite maior que 32 bits, você pode utilizar uma variável `uint64_t` (de `stdint.h`) para realizar essa operação.

---

Para saber processador faz, a melhor maneira é observar o código `assembly` gerado pelo compilador. Que no caso é esse (gerado pelo Visual Studio 2013):

```
; int x = 1;
mov DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], 1

; int x1 = (x << 1);
mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
shl eax, 1
mov DWORD PTR _x1$[ebp], eax
```

Nesse caso, tudo o que você quer saber é como a instrução `shl` funciona, que desloca o valor em `eax`. Agora, a forma como `shl` faz isso dependerá do processador.

Comment: <code>E se eu fizer:  
  
    int x = 1;
    x << 8;
  
x vai ser 0001 0000 0000 ?  

Se int tem 32 bits, o que acontece se eu "ultrapassar" este limite em deslocamento?  
Algo como:  
    x=1;  
    //Representação na memória:  
    //{4º byte} {3º byte} {2º byte} {1º byte}  
    //0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  
  
    x << 50;   
  
Como ficaria?</code>

Comment: No caso, você tem que atribuir o resultado a outra variável ou ao próprio `x`. Tipo: `int b = (x << 8)`.

Comment: Nota: right-shift em inteiros `signed` é *implementation defined*. Alguns compiladores usam shift aritmético enquanto outros usam o shift lógico. Faz diferença.

Comment: Se ultrapassar os limites (ou menor 0), acho que o resultado é indefinido e pode depender do compilador.

Comment: @Lucas pesquisei um pouco mais e vi que << >> são multiplicações e divisões por 2. Talvez o processador faça essas operações (multiplicação e divisão) e utilize um registrador temporário para armazenar os valores. Essas informações me bastam. Muito grato pela resposta e pela paciência. Sua resposta foi excelente.

Comment: Se ele ultrapassar o limite, não deveria ficar `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011`, por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Consulte qualquer documentação sobre C/C++, como por exemplo:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/
e veja os operadores definidos para a linguagem, seu significado e prioridade.

```
<< : deslocamento para a esquerda   
>> : deslocamento para a direita
```

Obs: não existem os operadores >>> e <<< em C/C++.