# O que acontece nestas linhas em C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, sintaxe

Está é uma rotina de leitura de um encoder que detecta qual sentido de rotação do encoder. As referencias são os pinos da esquerda e da direita apreciados como bits MSB e LSB. O Código funciona perfeitamente, mas eu não entendo o que acontece exatamente no trecho:

> int encoded = (MSB << 1) | LSB;
>
> int sum  = (lastEncoded << 2) | encoded;

Alguém saberia me explicar o que ocorre e como funcionam esses operadores das linhas acima? 
Segue a função completa...

```
void updateEncoder() {
t = micros();
MSB = digitalRead(encoderPin1); //MSB = most significant bit
LSB = digitalRead(encoderPin2); //LSB = least significant bit
int encoded = (MSB << 1) | LSB; //converting the 2 pin value to single number
int sum  = (lastEncoded << 2) | encoded; //adding it to the previous encoded value
if (sum == 0b1101 || sum == 0b0100 || sum == 0b0010 || sum == 0b1011) encoderValue ++;
if (sum == 0b1110 || sum == 0b0111 || sum == 0b0001 || sum == 0b1000) encoderValue --;
lastEncoded = encoded; //store this value for next time
t = micros() - t;
}
```

Grato.

Answer (score 4):

Isso é uma rotina de leitura similar à "bolinha" de mouse "antigo", e também usado em máquinas que eram comuns em "fliperamas", normalmente de carros de corrida, onde um anteparo redondo com pequenos cortes ou orifícios era posto na frente de 2 sensores óticos para a leitura do volante. Poderia muito bem ser usado numa esteira, com quadrados brancos e pretos propiciando leitura ótica, ou contatos mecânicos.

Os sensores são posicionados numa configuração de "quadratura", onde a sua sequência determina com precisão se o movimento é horário ou antihorário, de acordo com a sequência de "zeros e uns".

Matematicamente, é importante entender os operadores `<<` e `>>`, que já foram discutidos em outras questões.

> [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52949/para-que-servem-os-operadores)
>
> [Como funciona o deslocamento de bits em C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10174/como-funciona-o-deslocamento-de-bits-em-c-c)

Tomando as explicações das perguntas acima, **usando representação binária**, vamos analisar a primeira linha da pergunta:

```
int encoded = (MSB << 1) | LSB;
```

1. Supondo que MSB seja `01`, o operador `<<` efetivamente desloca o valor para a esquerda, e o resultado é `10`
2. Uma vez feito isso, o operador `|` (*or* binário) "mescla" o LSB com o MSB. Supondo que o LSB seja `1`, o resultado final será `11`
3. Da mesma forma, na linha seguinte:

   ```
   int sum = (lastEncoded << 2) | encoded;
   ```

   estamos pegando o `11` anterior, e deslocando duas casas para a esquerda, ou seja, transformando o valor em `1100`.
4. Finalmente, pegamos os dados da leitura anterior (obtida da mesma forma que os passos 1 e 2) e mesclamos com o valor da leitura atual. Supondo que a leitura atual seja `01` e a anterior `10`, temos o valor final `0110`.

Com isto, basta consultar a tabela de quadratura para saber se o valor deve ser incrementado ou decrementado.

### Sobre a "mecânica" da leitura

O segredo da leitura está no arranjo dos sensores, dispostos de forma que o orifício e as partes fechadas, ou contatos elétricos ocupem exatamente a distância dos dois sensores, de forma a acontecer o seguinte:

- 1 e 2 são os sensores
- AA é o anteparo (a luz não passa e o sensor indica 0)
- BB é abertura   (a luz passa e o sensor indica 1)

Partindo de uma hipotética posição inicial:

```
AABBAABBAABBAABB 
12                    Leitura: 00
```

Vamos supor que eu gire a roda ligeiramente para a direita:

```
ABBAABBAABBAABBA
12                    Leitura  01
```

Girando mais um pouco para a direita:

```
BBAABBAABBAABBAA
12                    Leitura  11
```

E mais um pouco:

```
BAABBAABBAABBAAB
12                    Leitura  10
```

No próximo giro, voltamos ao `00`.

Neste caso, qualquer par da sequência `00` `01` `11` `10` indica um passo à direita.

Supondo que fosse o contrário, a sequência seria `00` `10` `11` `01`, e qualquer combinação destes pares indica um passo à esquerda.

Indo mais além:

- se eu estiver na posição `00`, sei que o passo seguinte só pode ser `01` (direita), ou `10` (esquerda);
- se eu estiver na posição `01`, sei que o passo seguinte só pode ser `11` (direita), ou `00` (esquerda);
- se eu estiver na posição `11`, sei que o passo seguinte só pode ser `10` (direita), ou `01` (esquerda);
- finalmente, se eu estiver na posição `10`, sei que o passo seguinte só pode ser `00` (direita), ou `11` (esquerda);

O que o autor do código acima fez foi pegar essas regras e simplificar numa "tabelinha", para saber quando incrementar ou quando decrementar a variável.

<sub>De curiosidade, você pode notar que, consoante com as explicações dadas, não há na tabela do código original uma variação de 00 pra 11, nem de 10 pra 01 ou vice-versa, pois obrigatoriamente, pela disposição mecânica do sensor, um par em estado igual sempre é substituído por um par em estado diferente, e um par diferente sempre é substituído por um par igual caso haja movimento.</sub>