# Operador Bitwise Right

Tags: php, bitwise, bit

Olá

Realizando alguns estudos sobre o PHP me deparei com o bitwise e até então todas as suas operações não tem sido nada dificil, apenas o tal do right shift

Um exmeplo que peguei e ainda não entendi foi este:

```
print(4>>6); //onde o resultado final é igual a zero
```

E ao dar uma olhada em um livro percebi o seguinte calculo para esta expressao:

```
4/2^6
2^6 = 2*2*2*2*2*2=64
64/4 = 0,06
```

Que no caso ficaria igual a zero, que é o resultado que o php me retorna, embora eu pense que deveria dar 16.
Alguém poderia me explicar esta logica?

Comment: A linguagem é outra, mas o funcionamento é o mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja o 4 em base 2:

```
00000100
```

Agora vamos deslocar uma vez pra direita ( `4 >> 1` ):

```
00000010
```

Se deslocássemos duas vezes ( `4 >> 2` ):

```
00000001
```

Deslocando 6 casas, o bit foi "embora", por isso o resultado `0`.

Veja o deslocamento pra esquerda, vou pegar o número 6 como exemplo, e deslocar 2 vezes:

```
00000110 (6)

00011000 (6<<2 = 24)
```

Em resumo:

- quando você desloca pra **direita**, está **dividindo por 2** a cada passo.
- quando desloca pra **esquerda**, está **multiplicando por 2** a cada passo.

Veja mais detalhes aqui:

[Como funciona o deslocamento de bits em C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10174/70)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Bacco, o exemplo que peguei tbm estava errado conforme o Daniel informou, e desculpa pela duplicidade na pergunta

Comment: @tkmattos fechar por duplicata é apenas para concentrarmos as informações num lugar só, fique tranquilo que não é "penalização".

Answer (score 2):

O dividendo é 4 e o divisor é 64.

Na expressão está invertido.

O certo então é 4 / 64, cujo resultado é 0.0625

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda Daniel